# Will app_message_outbox_send() cause the Pebble to crash if there is no companion app?

Tags: android, c, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

I'm very new to Pebble Development, and I'm having trouble finding an answer to this. I'm wondering if you try to use `app_message_outbox_send();` and you don't have a companion app, will the Pebble app crash? I'm asking because that function call seems to be the culprit crashing my pebble app, and I don't have a companion app created for it yet. Also is there some way to see if there is a companion app on the phone or if the app is running?

Comment: Have you used the `app_message_register_` functions to set up `AppMessage`? `app_message_open()`? http://developer.getpebble.com/guides/pebble-apps/communications/appmessage/

Comment: Yes I have. Since then, I have fixed the problem although I'm not exactly sure what was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure when the problem was fixed, but I may have not been using `app_message_open()` or `app_message_register_*()` functions correctly.